# Enter or Exit trigger not get fired when i am using geofencing

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geofencing, android-geofence

I am using geofencing in my Android app following this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

I am creating and adding geofencing object in my default visible activity and listening to its events with the help IntentService as described in above link.

Geofence object successfully got added but when i tested it using real device and moved into/out of the defined geofence region, its ENTER/EXIT event does not get triggered.

I have tested it with a radius of 100m, 50m, 500m, 1500m and 2000m but it is not working in any of the case.

This is how i created and added geofencing:

```js
 mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(DashboardActivity.this);

Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(REQUEST_ID)

                .setCircularRegion(
                        22.703617,
                        75.873409,
                        Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )

                .build();
        mGeofenceList.add(geofence);

        GeofencingRequest geofencingRequest = new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
                .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER|GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
                .addGeofences(mGeofenceList).build();

        Intent intents = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
        mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DashboardActivity.this, 0, intents, PendingIntent.
                FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }else {
            mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, mGeofencePendingIntent)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.e("geofencing success", "successfully added");
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e("geofencing failure", "failed in added");

                }
            });
        }
```

To Listen to the ENTER/EXIT events i am using IntentService which is as follows:

```js
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GeofenceTransitionsIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        Toast.makeText(this,"service get start",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.e("service","geofencing service started");
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Toast.makeText(this,"error_in_geofancing"+errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
            // multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            Toast.makeText(this,"you are inside range",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geofenceTransition, triggeringGeofences);

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
          sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.e("geofancing","you are inside range");

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid_Transition",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
           // Context context,
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList <String>triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }
    }
```

I have added permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and LOCATION_HARDWARE for this.

Comment: Please go through this example its working fine for me. 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing